# Add/Change Array to/in existing PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session

I got following array in my PHP `$_SESSION`

```
[CART] => SHOPPINGCART OBJECT
       (
             [CONTENTS] => ARRAY
                  (
                     [121] => ARRAY
                        (
                            [QTY] => 1
                         )
```

I know how to change some simple `$_SESSION` variable, but what if there is an array in array and then there is the value I want to change? Or what if i wanted to add a new Array to `[CONTENTS]`? Sadly i couldn't find a solution on here.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in the array?

Comment: In this case for example I want to change the QTY from 1 to 5

Comment: @monace19 You might want to rethink that based on `[CART] => SHOPPINGCART OBJECT`

Comment: @monace19 Nope, not working. And it is possible that there are 2 or 3 QTY in session, but only one which belongs to [121] so it has to be specified somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $_SESSION array actually contains an OBJECT which contains and ARRAY which contains an ARRAY

So using normal notation to access QTY for example you would do

```
echo $_SESSION['CART']->CONTENTS[121]['QTY'];
```

Or changing the QTY

```
$_SESSION['CART']->CONTENTS[121]['QTY'] = 10;
```

Adding a new array to CONTENTS would be

```
$_SESSION['CART']->CONTENTS[] = array('QTY' => 2);
```

Then viewing all the CONTENTS array you could do

```
foreach ( $_SESSION['CART']->CONTENTS as $id => $content ) {
    echo "$id\n"
    foreach ( $content as $qty ) {
        echo "    $qty\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets me a Parse Error: 
PARSE ERROR(4): "syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'"

Comment: Sorry missed the 121 occurance, see amended example

Comment: 2 seconds I will test

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski use this `$_SESSION['CART']` instead `$_SESSION->['CART']`

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski Thats it, got a bit confused there for a second. Thanks for spotting the typo

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you guys, this is working out! If I add something i have to start with (in my example) the [121] because this is a products_id, I would then add for example products_id [130] with an own quantity, but i will manage to edit the code this way :)

Answer (score 0):

One could use a combination of serialize()/unserialize().
To store it in a session:

```
$cart= new SHOPPINGCART();
$_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($cart);
```

To actually change values from it:

```
$cart = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
// do anything with cart and store it afterwards with the code above
$cart["quantity"] += 1; // increment it by one
$_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($cart);
```

Comment: He is not asking how to store it, he is asking how to access what is already stored, presumably by something he has not written himself

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = $_SESSION['CART'];
$temp->CONTENTS['121']['QTY'] = 5;
$_SESSION['CART'] = $temp;
```

Check if this works; then we can think of a way for specifying "121".